# Entity Framework Data Base First error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

tengo una base de datos en postgres que consta de 3 tablas.

```sql
create table users (
    user_id serial4 primary key,
    name VARCHAR not null,
    lastname VARCHAR not null,
    email varchar not null,
    phone varchar not null,
    country varchar not null,
    logical_delete BOOLEAN default false
);

create table roles (
    role_id serial4 primary key,
    name varchar not null
);

create table user_roles (
    user_id integer not null,
    role_id integer not null
);

alter table user_roles add FOREIGN key (user_id) references users(user_id);
alter table user_roles add FOREIGN key (role_id) references roles(role_id);
```

Al ejecutar la linea correspondiente para generar las clases para esas tablas:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "ConnectionString" Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL -o Models
```

me da el siguiente error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpDbContextGenerator.TransformText()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpModelGenerator.ProcessTemplate(ITextTransformation transformation)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpModelGenerator.GenerateModel(IModel model, ModelCodeGenerationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineerScaffolder.ScaffoldModel(String connectionString, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions databaseOptions, ModelReverseEngineerOptions modelOptions, ModelCodeGenerationOptions codeOptions)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContext(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1 tables, String modelNamespace, String contextNamespace, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames, Boolean suppressOnConfiguring, Boolean noPluralize)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContextImpl(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputDbContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemaFilters, IEnumerable`1 tableFilters, String modelNamespace, String contextNamespace, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames, Boolean suppressOnConfiguring, Boolean noPluralize)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContext.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Al quitar de mi base de datos las Foreing keys el comando se ejecuta sin errores.

En que me estoy equivocando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despues de mucho buscar me di cuenta que faltaba agregarle la Primary Key a la tabla user_roles

El script, quedaria asi:

```
create table users (
    user_id serial4 primary key,
    name VARCHAR not null,
    lastname VARCHAR not null,
    email varchar not null,
    phone varchar not null,
    country varchar not null,
    logical_delete BOOLEAN default false
);

create table roles (
    role_id serial4 primary key,
    name varchar not null
);

create table user_roles (
    user_id integer primary key not null,
    role_id integer primary key not null
);

alter table user_roles add FOREIGN key (user_id) references users(user_id);
alter table user_roles add FOREIGN key (role_id) references roles(role_id);
```